# PHP Saving Obj in session then changing it's value on another page

Tags: php, session-variables

I am new in OOP with PHP and I'm trying to do something like this:
Class entry form is inside it's own file.
index.php creates an object from class entry form and stores it in session.
page1.php - I want to be able to call this object back and run some methods on it to modify it's values. Except this is not working...

So the work flow is as follows 
index->page1

I'm trying to grasp the concept of object orriented programming. And i'm starting to get it. 
Is what I'm trying to do wrong? is this possible?

```
//page1.php

    include('entry.class.php');
    session_start();

    print_r($_SESSION['entry']);
    $entry = unserialize($_SESSION['Entry']);
    $entry->set_category('Asian');
    $entry->set_upload('http://paypal.com');

    print_r($entry);

//index.php
    session_start();
    include('entry.class.php');

    $entry = new entryForm();
    $entry->set_category('Blondes');
    $entry->set_upload('http://google.com');


    $_SESSION['entry'] = serialize($entry);

    print_r($entry);
    print_r($_SESSION['entry']);


//class entryform   


    class entryForm{


                            var $category;
                            var $upload;

                            function set_category($new_category)
                            {
                                    $this->category = $new_category;
                            }

                            function get_category()
                            {
                                    return $this->category;
                            }

                            function set_upload($new_upload)
                            {
                                    $this->upload = $new_upload;
                            }

                            function get_upload()
                            {
                                    return $this->upload;
                            }

                    }
```

Comment: Hmm, `set_category('Blondes')`, `set_category('Asian')`. I see what kind of site you're building there ;)

Comment: LOL Actually it's hair stylist competition form....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your unserialize you wrote the 'Entry' Uppercase. while in the serialize you wrote 'entry', lowercase

Comment: Nyammmm!!! That was it!!

Comment: is it a must to serialize the object variable entry? and unserialize on the following page?